# Tuple of Templated class with different Variadic Arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, tuples

I am trying to construct a tuple of a classes templated with different arguments as below but fails to see how.

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    A(T d) : m_t(d) {}

private:
    double m_t;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct B
{
    std::tuple<A<Ts>...> m_tuple;
    
    template<class... Args>
    B(Args&&... args)
    {
        // How can I do:
        // N = number of Args
        // m_tuple = {A<Args[0]>(args[0]), A<Args[1]>(args[1]), ..., A<Args[N]>(args[N])};
    }
};
```

Comment: `m_tuple = {A<Args>(args)...};`? Or better `std::forward<Args>(args)` instead of `args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) as shown below. Also note that we're using **member initializer list** to do initialzation of `m_tuple` instead of assignment inside the ctor body:

Here we use `std::forward`:

```
template<class... Args>
B(Args&&... args): m_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{
        
}
```